# How do I get cancelOrder() to work? (wix-velo API)

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend, velo

Here's the API backend reference:
https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pricing-plans-backend/orders/cancelorder

I've installed Wix Pricing Plans to my Wix-site (no code required), but it does not give my members the option to cancel their recurring plan.

I don't want to cancel their plans manually, upon request, I'm looking to coding to handle it immediately, upon request (eg. `onClick` of a button).

The linked reference gives this example:

**Cancel an order immediately, bypassing permission checks**

```
import { orders } from 'wix-pricing-plans-backend';

/* Sample orderId value: 'a8c4a1b2-b5e8-4b33-9693-057ec93e9a27'
 * 
 * Sample effectiveAt value: 'IMMEDIATELY'
 * 
 * Sample options value:
 * {
 *   suppressAuth: true
 * }
 */

export async function myCancelOrderWithOptionsFunction(orderId, effectiveAt, options) {
  try {
    const order = await orders.cancelOrder(orderId, effectiveAt, options);

    return order;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

// Returns a promise that resolves to void
```

I've tried to implement this, but I'm new to working with backend to frontend code, and don't know how to do it.

I know how to add a backend module, but I don't know what code to add there and what corresponding code to add in the frontend.

I hope you all can help.

Ultimately I would need to get all orders connected to the `wixUsers.currentUser.id`, and then run the `cancelOrder()` function on those `orderId`'s

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I fought with this exact implementation for the past 3 or 4 days. I originally wanted to call the cancelOrder on the onplanpurchased event (https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-pricing-plans-backend/events/onplanpurchased). This did not work for me. Instead, I started a custom flow on the subscribe page that would start an online purchase when the URL had query strings with order details. I used checkout.startOnlinePurchase(myquerystringplanid) to start a checkout with the pricing plan the user had chosen. Inside of this promise I got the active subscriptions for the current user orders.memberListOrders({"orderStatus": ["ACTIVE"]}). I then had to filter out the current order by id then call cancelOrder on the backend using a web module. Here are the code snippets:

```
// FRONT END CODE (Subscribe page inside $w.onReady)
import { checkout } from 'wix-pricing-plans-frontend';
import { orders } from 'wix-pricing-plans.v2';
import { removeAllExistingSub } from "backend/backend-cancel-all-current.web";
checkout.startOnlinePurchase(wixLocation.query.planid).then((checkoutdata) => {

            //console.log(checkoutdata)
            const checkOrderStatus = []
            const orderStatus = {
                orderStatuses: checkOrderStatus
            }
            orderStatus.orderStatuses.push("ACTIVE")
            orders.memberListOrders(orderStatus).then((order) => {
                var newOrder = order.orders.filter((curor) => curor._id !== checkoutdata.order._id)
                newOrder.forEach((ordertocancel) => {
                    console.log(ordertocancel)
                    removeAllExistingSub(ordertocancel)

                })
            })

        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

```
// BACKEND FUNCTION CALL
import { Permissions, webMethod } from 'wix-web-module';
import { orders } from 'wix-pricing-plans.v2';
import { elevate } from 'wix-auth';
const elevatedCancelOrder = elevate(orders.cancelOrder);
export const removeAllExistingSub = webMethod(Permissions.Anyone,
    (subid) => {
        //let effectivenow = "IMMEDIATELY"
        console.log(subid)
        // The 2nd argument may complain that string "IMMEDIATELY" is not a valid type. The implementation still works despite this error. I opened a Velo ticket regarding this
        elevatedCancelOrder(subid._id, "IMMEDIATELY").catch((err) => {
            console.log("err cancelling")
            console.log(err)
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thank you @zach-anton -- I found a solution that cancels all orders of the current member upon them clicking a button. It's not ideal, but I have more urgent to-do's at the moment, so I've saved your answer and will come back once i reach the relevant point in my to-do list. Again, thanks a lot for your answer, and I'll probably be back within two-three months, when it's time to smooth out the user experience. Cheers!